# Can you please tell me why I'm having this error message on solidity in remix

Tags: solidity

from solidity:

```
simplestorage.sol:14:3: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
  people[] public people;
  ^--------------------^
simplestorage.sol:9:3: The previous declaration is here:
  struct people {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

what does it mean

Comment: Please add proper information while asking a question. It's hard to answer with the limited info which you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is the capitalization issue here.

Please check when creating the people struct you named it "people" or "People". It is possible that you named your struct as "People". In that case the code should look like follow:

People[] public people;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).