# How can i avoid the declaration error in solidity

Tags: list, solidity, remix

I am trying  to learn blockchain developing(solidity) with the help of  tutorial video.and i am very new for this.There is a error while practicing the programming,please help me to avoid this error.and please let me know what is the reason for this error.

the error occurred for this line:

```
people[] public people;
```

The error is,

```
 DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
  --> smart.sol:20:5:
   |
20 |     people[] public people;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: The previous declaration is here:
  --> smart.sol:11:5:
   |
11 |     struct people {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsml4.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include ALL of your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: However, the error seems clear: you have two identifiers **`people` the struct** and **`people` the property**.  The compiler is telling you that you can't do that and must rename one of them.  (Probably you should find a better tutorial, looks like somebody else had the [exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72677585/3744182).)

Comment: After you [edit] your question to include all your code as text, should I make that an answer?